# Drupal External API Get Data with Load More

Tags: drupal-9

I have written a code which gets a list of jobs from external application using GuzzleHttp. Currenly the list shows first 15 jobs. The API url needs limit & offset parameter to display other set of results. But I am not sure how will pass them as parameter and also add a **Load More** button to display more jobs like pagination.

The API URL with limit & offset will be like this:

- For 1st page:
  https://myexternaldomain.com/api/myportal/v1/job?offset=0&limit=25
- For 2nd page:
  https://myexternaldomain.com/api/myportal/v1/job?offset=25&limit=25
- For 3rd page:
  https://myexternaldomain.com/api/myportal/v1/job?offset=50&limit=25

and so on.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

class JobsListBlock extends BlockBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
    public function build() {
        
        $client = new Client(['headers' => ['Authorization' => 'MY_AUTHORIZE_KEY', 'apikey' => 'MY_API_KEY']]);
        $jobsList = [];

        try {
            $response = $client->get('https://myexternaldomain.com/api/myportal/v1/job');
            $result = json_decode($response->getBody(), TRUE);
            foreach($result['response'] as $item) {
                $jobsList[] = array(
                    'jobCode' => $item['jobCode'],
                    'jobTitle' => $item['jobTitle']
                ); 
            }
        }
        catch (RequestException $e) {
            // log exception
            echo 'api not working';
        }
        return array(
            '#theme' => 'mytheme_jobs_list_block',
            '#jobs_list' => $jobsList
        );
    }
}
```